# Linux access control policies sudoers

Tags: linux, access-control, file-system, sudoers

I'm learning about linux hardening and I'm creating a sudoers file. My idea is to separate things. There will be a user to see log files, another that can sudo to manage system processes, another for network managements, and so on and so forth. Is this overkill and safe or just overkill?

I'm using groups to do so, like user network belongs to system-network group and it can sudo certain bins. But I also want to use this group method for the filesystem. like only process user can go to the proc directory. Is this doable with groups?

Answer (score 1):

Whether it's overkill or not depends on your use cases and your risk assessment.  It sounds like you're describing Role-based Access Control (RBAC).  RBAC is a popular method to help enable segregation of duties and regulatory compliance.

> Access control based on user roles (i.e., a collection of access authorizations a user receives based on an explicit or implicit assumption of a given role). Role permissions may be inherited through a role hierarchy and typically reflect the permissions needed to perform defined functions within an organization. A given role may apply to a single individual or to several individuals.

I'm assuming you mean "doable with groups in sudo".  The short answer is yes but you need to be very careful how it's implemented.  With `sudo` you are granting root-level access to commands to an individual or a group (role) that individual is in.  `sudo` is very literal and if you don't consider how commands could be abused you may be providing more access than you expect.  For example allowing the logs group to `cat` everything in /var/log:

```
User_Alias LOGS = blah 
LOGS    ALL = (root) /bin/cat /var/log/*
```

Allows the user to `cat` the /etc/shadow file:

```
[blah@ip-10-99-1-27 ~]$ cat /var/log/../../../../../etc/shadow
cat: /var/log/../../../../../etc/shadow: Permission denied

blah@ip-10-99-1-27 ~]$ sudo cat /var/log/../../../../../etc/shadow
[sudo] password for blah:
root:$6$RxAj<redacted>*********************:16741:0:99999:7:::
blah:$6$B70t<redacted>*********************:19114:0:99999:7:::
```

In general, `sudo` is one method for granting role-based access but you need to be conscious that you could be providing more access than you intended.

**References**
[NIST RBAC Models](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Role-Based-Access-Control/documents/sandhu96.pdf)
[NIST RBAC Definition](https://csrc.nist.gov/glossary/term/rbac)

Comment: With groups I want to avoid such problems, like the one you described with var. I'm finding this to be a lot of work, because implementing it I need to know a lot about the users or apps that I have on the system and theirs needs. 

If I close the /var directory with `root:var-group 750`, **apt** for example with **_apt** user gets messed up. So I have to add **_apt** to **var-group** and also everything that uses, or will use /var